# Is there a way to know if a user exists when a password reset email is sended with Firebase Authentication in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have to know if the email is not registered when the password reset email is sended.

This is my code:

```dart
/// Sends a password reset email to the given [email] address.
/// Throws a [SendPasswordResetEmailFailure] if an exception occurs.
Future<void> sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) async {
  try {
    await _firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    throw SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.fromFirebaseAuthException(e);
  } catch (_) {
    throw const SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.failure();
  }
}
```

send_password_reset_email_failure.dart

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'send_password_reset_email_failure.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class SendPasswordResetEmailFailure
    with _$SendPasswordResetEmailFailure
    implements Exception {
  const factory SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.failure() =
      SendPasswordResetEmailDefaultFailure;

  const factory SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.invalidEmail() =
      SendPasswordResetEmailInvalidEmailFailure;

  const factory SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.userNotFound() =
      SendPasswordResetEmailUserNotFoundFailure;

  factory SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.fromFirebaseAuthException(
    FirebaseAuthException exception,
  ) {
    switch (exception.code) {
      case 'invalid-email':
        return const SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.invalidEmail();
      case 'user-not-found':
        return const SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.userNotFound();
      default:
        return const SendPasswordResetEmailFailure.failure();
    }
  }
}
```

From the doc of the method sendPasswordResetEmail it says the following:

```
/// May throw a [FirebaseAuthException] with the following error codes:
/// ...
/// - **auth/user-not-found**\
///   Thrown if there is no user corresponding to the email address
```

But the error is never thrown when I use an email that is not registered.

I tried with fetchSignInMethodsForEmail method but I receive an empty array every time (with valid emails).

I also tried checking with signInWithEmailAndPassword method but throws *INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS* exception, even when the email doesn't exists.

Comment: So you basically say that you receive a reset password email even if the user with that email doesn't exist in the Firebase Authentication?

Comment: No, I don't receive that email if the email doesn't exists in Firebase. But I want to show a message like "The email is not found"

Comment: When you're using  `.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email)` have you tried to catch an `Exception` and not a `FirebaseAuthException`? Are you getting some other message?

Comment: Yes, I tried but don't catch anything

Comment: So you say there is no Exception thrown when the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, that it's the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255952/discussion-between-santiago-curvello-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know the email is not registered before sending out the email and you don't want to query your own database for the account.

If yes, then try to signInWithEmailAndPassword, and catch for [firebase_auth/user-not-found]. If it's failed with other cause, then go ahead and sending reset password email. Otherwise, popup with right message.

Bear in mind that intended failed sign in costs one attempt on any rate limit.

---

With sample code:

```
try {
    final signIn = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: 'notfound@any.com', password: 'abc');
    print(signIn.user);
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
    print(e.code);
}
```

Comment: I tried checking with signInWithEmailAndPassword method but throws INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS exception, even when the email doesn't exists. I never receive user-not-found

Comment: I've edited with sample code, can you try again with that? I've tested with firebase emulator and it did throw the 'user-not-found' code. Did you check with empty password?